# Hard disk 3f0 error: How I can I retrieve files from separate drive on same computer?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

The other day, when turning my laptop on, I got a "Hard disk 3f0 error", and it appears that the drive is completely broken - or at least, I haven't been able to find a way of fixing this...

The drive that Windows is installed on is an SSD drive, but the laptop also has a separate HDD on which I have backed up a number of files.

I would assume that given Windows is installed on the SSD, this is the drive which is having the hard disk 3f0 error, but that the HDD drive should still be fine & working normally.

How can I access the HDD in order to retrieve the files stored on it? Is it as simple as connecting a network cable from the broken laptop to another computer, or is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The other day, when turning my laptop on, I got a "Hard disk 3f0
> error", and it appears that the drive is completely broken

That is likely the case - that the hard drive has failed.

Courses of action:

1. Move it (in a carrier) to another machine and see if you can read it on another machine. This might possibly work.  Carriers for both Hard Drives and SSD drives are commonly available.
2. If the data is important, consider getting an assessment for recovery from a local data recovery agency.   Do the recovery agency assessment before recovery software on the Internet.
3. If you wish to try, the following software is reasonable:   Recuva (CC Cleaner); Easus recovery software; and Spinrite (Gibson Research). These tools are commonly available on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - just to check: are the actions you've listed for recovering data from the SSD or the HDD? I'm not so worried about what was on the SSD, which I believe to be the drive which has failed - I'm more concerned about getting hold of what is on the HDD. When you say "move it (in a carrier) to another machine", do you mean to physically remove the HDD from the laptop and plug it into another computer?

Comment: The tools I listed (common tools easily available) can work on HDD or SSD. If the SSD has failed, you need a device that can accept the SSD. I do not have one of those at this point.  Yes, I mean remove the drive from one machine and try reading it in another machine.

Comment: I don't need to retrieve anything from the SSD (which I believe to be the drive which has failed). I'm looking to try and retrieve data (backed up photos, etc) from the HDD. When you say to move it in a carrier, is that referring to a USB to SATA reader?

Comment: When you say to move it in a carrier, is that referring to a USB to SATA reader?    ..... Yes. There are a variety of carriers that can do this. I happen to use a Sabrent.

Comment: Thanks, just hadn't come across the term 'carrier' in this context before, so wasn't sure exactly what you meant by that. I don't really know much at all about hardware!